# Pandas - properly indexing by position on integer axis and label on the other (to avoid chained assignment)

Tags: python, pandas

I am aware that pandas provides:

1. `.ix` - mixed label and position indexing (primarily label), if index is integer - it will be interpreted as label
2. `.loc` - explicit indexing by label
3. `.iloc` - explicit indexing by position

That's cool.

What would be the proper way to index the columns by label (ala `.loc`) and rows by position (ala `.iloc`) in one shot to avoid chained assignment? Preferably, it would avoid `reset_index()`.

To provide an example, assuming the following DataFrame `df`:

```
   col1  col2  col3
3     1     4     2
2     2     3     3
4     3     2     1
1     4     1     4
```

Does pandas have something like `some_indexer`, which behaves as follows?

```
In[2]: df.some_indexer[2,'col2':'col3']
Out[2]:
col2    2
col3    1
Name: 4, dtype: object
```

Thanks!

Comment: This won't work because you have an ambiguous index so this for instance does not do what you want: `df.ix[2, 'col2':'col3']`, you could only do this doing `df.iloc[2]['col2','col3']` but this is chained indexing, if your index was reindexed so starting from `0` or a str then `df.ix[2, 'col2':'col3']` would work

Comment: @MaximHaytovich the OP is asking for the ith row, 2 in this case, and then just that column range so in this case it would be the 3rd row as this is row(2) as indices are 0 based

Comment: @EdChum ```df.ix[2, 'col2':'col3']``` wouldn't "fail", it just wouldn't return what I want it to :) 
So far ```reset_index()``` seems to make most sense.

Comment: I updated my comment, but you get my point about the ambiguous behaviour, I can post an answer to show how this could work

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but this can indeed be done without chained indexing or using `reset_index()`. You just need to use `df.index[2]` inside the `.loc` indexer.

```
df.loc[df.index[2],'col2':'col3']
```

This will also work correctly with assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we would do `df.ix[2, 'col2':'col3']` but because your index is ambiguous you get the 2nd rather than the 3rd row as `2` appears as a value in the index at position 1 so the label selection succeeds as `ix` tries label selection first and then position selection.

From the docs:

> .ix supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily
>   label based, but will fall back to integer positional access unless
>   the corresponding axis is of integer type. .ix is the most general and
>   will support any of the inputs in .loc and .iloc. .ix also supports
>   floating point label schemes. .ix is exceptionally useful when dealing
>   with mixed positional and label based hierachical indexes.

```
In [246]:

df.ix[2,'col2':'col3']
Out[246]:
col2    3
col3    3
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

The following would work but this is chained calling and assignments are likely to operate on a copy and raise a warning:

```
In [247]:

df.iloc[2][['col2','col3']]
Out[247]:
col2    2
col3    1
Name: 4, dtype: int64
```

The simplest thing would be to reset the index and then you can call `ix`, we have to drop the index again as this is inserted as a column:

```
In [250]:

df = df.reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
df
Out[250]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     2
1     2     3     3
2     3     2     1
3     4     1     4
In [251]:

df.ix[2,'col2':'col3']
Out[251]:
col2    2
col3    1
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Agreed. Was wondering if it can be done w/o ```reset_index()```.

Comment: You could reassign the index that would be less typing e.g. `df.index = np.arange(len(df))`

Comment: Also, the chained calling would fail on assignment of ['a','b'] for example. I.e., it would assign to a copy.