# Why does pandas dataframe indexing change axis depending on index type?

Tags: python, pandas

when you index into a pandas dataframe using a list of ints, it returns columns.

e.g. `df[[0, 1, 2]]`  returns the first three columns.

why does indexing with a boolean vector return a list of rows?

e.g. `df[[True, False, True]]` returns the first and third rows. (and errors out if there aren't 3 rows.)

why? Shouldn't it return the first and third columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very specific slicing accessors to target rows and columns in specific ways.

[Mixed Position and Label Based Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699597/pandas-properly-indexing-by-position-on-integer-axis-and-label-on-the-other-t)

[Select by position](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer)

[Selection by Label](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/indexing.html#selection-by-label)

- `loc[]`, `at[]`, and `get_value()` take row and column labels and return the appropriate slice
- `iloc[]` and `iat[]` take row and column positions and return the appropriate slice

What you are seeing is the result of `pandas` trying to infer what you are trying to do.  As you have noticed this is inconsistent at times.  In fact, it is more pronounced than just what you've highlighted... but I wont go into that now.

See also

[pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html)

> ```
> However, when an axis is integer based,
> ONLY label based access and not positional access is supported.
> Thus, in such cases, it’s usually better to be explicit and use .iloc or .loc.
> ```

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with .loc, .ix, and .iloc. Thanks for introducing me to the other methods!

Comment: Don't know how to edit comments... anyway, the tutorial I'm going through does it like my original question, which I don't agree with. I always use loc, iloc or ix. However, I still wanted to understand what's going on under the hood, so I can read other people's code.

Comment: @piRSquared
The same for `df[1]` returns column but `df[1:3]` returns rows?

Answer (score 2):

Because if use:

```
df[[True, False, True]]
```

it is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by mask:

```
[True, False, True]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

print (df[[True, False, True]])
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
2  3  6  9
```

Boolean mask is same as:

```
print (df.B != 5)
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: B, dtype: bool

print (df[df.B != 5])
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: Yes, I understand how boolean indexing works. But why does it index on axis=0 and not axis=1? Why is pandas' indexing behaviour inconsistent?

if i did df[[0, 1, 2]] it would return 
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

Comment: Yes, I understand how boolean indexing works. But why does it index on axis=0 and not axis=1? Why is pandas' indexing behaviour inconsistent? if i did df[[0, 1, 2]] it would return 
`
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

Comment: ahhh formatting! 

 if i did df[[0, 2]] it would return 
`
   A   C
0  1   7
1  2   8
2  3   9
`
and now its indexing on axis=1.

it should be consistent and return:

`

   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
2  3  6  9

`
where its indexing on axis=0.

Comment: Yes, it is subset of data - select columns. It is same as `df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 2]]`

Comment: Yes, but i still don't understand. 

Why does `df[[0, 2]]` behave like `df.iloc[:,[0, 2]]`

but `df[[True, False, True]]` behave like `df.iloc[[0, 2], :]`?

Comment: I mean, why does indexing with a list of **ints** select **columns*, but indexing with a **boolean vector** select **rows**? Thanks for your patience!